# Is there an easy way of calculating number of IPs from 2 given IP addresses?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to calculate number of number of IP addresses from 2 given IP addresses.

Example: 127.0.1.10 and 127.0.0.200 is 67 IP addresses..

What's easy way of doing this?

I've seen other examples, but I'm looking for a Python example. Thanks.

Comment: So you're essentially asking how to do base-256 subtraction?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Convert the IPs to numbers, then subtract.

Comment: for more general IP calculation, like listing out the IPs in a `/24` network, see https://docs.python.org/3/howto/ipaddress.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> import socket
>>> def iptoint(ip):
...     return int(socket.inet_aton(ip).encode('hex'), 16)
... 
>>> iptoint('127.0.0.200')
2130706632
>>> iptoint('127.0.1.10') - iptoint('127.0.0.200')
66
>>> def ipdistance(ip1, ip2):
...     return abs(iptoint(ip1) - iptoint(ip2)) + 1
... 
>>> ipdistance('127.0.1.10', '127.0.0.200')
67
```